# mongostat output does not correspond to db.currentOp()

Tags: mongodb, database

We have a mongodb 2.3.4 server. db.currentOp() consistently yields:

```
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
```

Indicating that the system is... not doing much of anything.

But mongostat shows around a few thousand updates per second:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults               locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0     *0   1008     *0       0  1009|0       0  2284g  4570g  23.3g      0 xxxxx:24.7%          0       0|0     0|0     1m   106k    75   19:19:43 
    *0     *0    982     *0       0   983|0       0  2284g  4570g  23.3g      0 xxxxx:24.6%          0       0|0     0|0     1m   103k    75   19:19:44 
    *0     13   1002     *0       0  1009|0       0  2284g  4570g  23.3g      0 xxxxx:24.6%          0       0|0     0|1     1m   113k    76   19:19:45 
    *0      3   1019     *0       0  1022|0       0  2284g  4570g  23.3g      0 xxxxx:24.9%          0       0|0     0|0     1m   109k    75   19:19:46
```

There's no replication on the machine. Additionally, there are a few update queries showing up in the logs, but nowhere near hundreds per second.

What could account for this discrepancy?

[Update: db.currentOp(true) shows a large number of operations that appear to be inactive but not waiting for locks. Are these shown in mongostat? What could they be doing?]

Comment: Have you enabled authorization?

Comment: Does that make a difference?